# usage of @apiParam in apiDoc

Tags: java, api-doc

I use apiDoc for documenting Java and would like to use @apiParam to show that an input parameter can be of different types. For example:the type may be Map,Collection,Set,List and the like.How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

@apiParam(allowableValues = "projects,issueTypes,projects;;;issueTypes", required = false, value = "You can specify one or more keys as comma separated list")

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much!Maybe I don't clarify my question clearly enough.I'm sorry for that.My question is that suppose the specific type of parameter is Collection<Object>,List<Object>,Map<Object,Object>,etc in java,and what the corresponding value of type of @apiParam is.